# Pycharm cannot find libraries from remote virtualenv, even when correct interpreter specified

Tags: python, ssh, pycharm, virtualenv

I want to use Pycharm as IDE to upload my python code to a remote server. On this server I have a virtual environment with virtualenv. This interpreter is specified in the project interpreter settings and when I look at the installed packages, it finds all the packages, but when I program, all the imports I use are not found and hence autocomplete does not work and my whole code is full of errors which is quite annoying. I use Pycharm on a windows computer and the server runs on Ubuntu 14.04.

[image: Print screen of pycharm settings]
As can be seen on the figure, the project interpreter uses an ssh connection to the server, and my path to the python interpreter is set to the python interpreter of the virtual environment (not the default python on that server). All the installed packages are also shown. Should I configure something else to make Pycharm find these modules (allthough I think pycharm finds them as they show up in the picture, but it does not use them for imports)?

Comment: I use this all the time and it works well; Try to reach out the official support channels, they will help you nail the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but not with a remote interpreter.

I found that the *Run Configuration* was set to use a different interpreter than the *Project Settings*.

> **Settings / Preferences** > Project: untitled > Project Interpreter =>
>   ~/project/venv/bin/python

All good. But:

> **Run Configuration** > Python interpreter => /usr/local/bin/python3.7

The top choice on the drop-down list for the Run Configuration interpreters was **Project Default** which set it to the same as my project setting.

> **Run Configuration** > Python interpreter => Project Default
>   (~/project/venv/bin/python)

I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but it's something to check.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [PY-29551](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29551) PyCharm does not yet support remote virtual environments with remote interpreters (only global Python environments). Apparently they will add this any moment in [PY-6002](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-6002).

Until then I solved this with the workaround suggested in [PY-29551](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29551):

For simply deploying and running code the workaround with adding a "pseudo" python executable that just loads the venv before running python worked for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /home/me/mypy/venv/bin/activate
exec python $*
```

Just add this to your remote venv and select it as Python executable instead.

For remote debugging this did not work for me, so for debugging I instead went for the Remote Debug Server approach described in the [offical PyCharm docs on remote debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config).