# Module ‘wandb’ has no attribute ‘apis’

Tags: python, machine-learning, wandb

I’m trying to use wandb in a project I’m running on a server via SSH. I created and configured the virtual environment, but with wandb, I’m encountering the error ‘module ‘wandb’ has no attribute ‘apis’’. The server is running Python 3.6.8 and has wandb-0.15.12 installed. However, when I use ‘wandb login’ or any other wandb command, it throws the error. Could anyone help me resolve this issue?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/bin/wandb", line 5, in <module>
    from wandb.cli.cli import cli
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from wandb import sdk as wandb_sdk
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/sdk/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .artifacts.artifact import Artifact  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/sdk/artifacts/artifact.py", line 36, in <module>
    from wandb.apis.normalize import normalize_exceptions
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/apis/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .public import Api as PublicApi  # noqa
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/apis/public.py", line 51, in <module>
    from wandb.sdk.launch.errors import LaunchError
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/sdk/launch/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._launch import launch
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/sdk/launch/_launch.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .agent import LaunchAgent
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/sdk/launch/agent/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .agent import LaunchAgent
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/sdk/launch/agent/agent.py", line 15, in <module>
    from wandb.sdk.launch._launch_add import launch_add
  File "/home/tcouto/mestrado_andrey/psla/venv-psla/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wandb/sdk/launch/_launch_add.py", line 5, in <module>
    import wandb.apis.public as public
AttributeError: module 'wandb' has no attribute 'apis'
```

I tried to reinstall and set it up in another virtual environment, but the same error keeps happening, and don't have any other file with that name inside the folder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Do you have any files in your script directory that has the name ```wandb.py```?

Comment: @ewokx No, I don't have any other file with that name inside the folder

Comment: What's the output of these commands: (2 separate lines):

    import wandb;

    dir(wandb)

Comment: @hikerjobs i create .py  file, paste these commands and execute the file, the output is the same error "module 'wandb' has no attribute 'apis'"

Comment: Try reinstalling the wandb module.  (Crediting this link:https://github.com/wandb/wandb/issues/1186 though I'm not sure this will help...  )

Comment: I mean just run those two commands above - the "import wandb" line and then the "dir(wandb)" line. Don't import anything else.
You can also do this directly from the command line. Type "python" to start Python and then run those two commands one after the other.

Comment: @hikerjobs Okay, I followed your instructions. The 'import wandb' presented the same error, and 'dir(wandb)' showed the error: 'name 'wandb' is not defined.'

Comment: @ewokx I have already followed these instructions in the link, but it didn't help much

Comment: If "import wandb" is giving you an error, that it means either it is not installed or your environment is not able to find it. Giving that you're doing a remote ssh, it seems to be something with your environment. Take a look at this for some pointers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443288/pycharm-cannot-find-libraries-from-remote-virtualenv-even-when-correct-interpre  and search for other questions from that perspective. The "remote ssh" seems to be the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the wandb version to wandb==0.15.11